# What's going on? my vim highlight some word which I dont't want to

Tags: vim-syntax-highlighting

[image]

Who can tell me why 'UI','molokai colorscheme','statusline' look like this?
which option can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because the way VIM performs code coloring.

I guess it is not performing full parse of the code, but partial, REGEX based keyword detection. The REGEX is probably wrong.